Coupling simulations with different time-steps
Suppose I have two fluid solvers which which operate on two spatial domains which share a common boundary. I want to run them separately, and couple them.
Do I need run them at the same time-step? Or, can I, to take an example, run one solver at $\Delta t$ and the other at $100\Delta t$ if their stable timesteps are radically different?
What are other things I need to consider or be aware of?
What are the canonical references in this area and what keywords do I need to be aware of?
I'd imagine that researchers working on Fluid Structure Interaction or on coupling atomistic models to continuum models or on Domain Decomposition have considered these issues.
I'd be very grateful for any pointers to the literature.

The answer depends strongly on the order of accuracy you hope to achieve.  For first-order accuracy, you can use different time step sizes and just do linear interpolation.  For higher order accuracy, it's more complicated and depends on what kind of time integration you're using.
In most ways, what you want to do is not very different from a more common case: you have a differential equation with multiple terms (say, representing different physical effects) and you want to integrate them separately but couple the result.  The key words to look for are operator splitting or fractional step methods.  A more specific term you could read about is multirate methods.
You can read about some of these topics, for instance, in the last chapter of Leveque's finite difference book.  For a more in-depth treatment, see the book of Hundsdorfer & Verwer.  For multirate methods, I'm not aware of a good textbook treatment; it's very much an active area of research.  You could for instance look at Steven Robert's thesis, and per the comment below he recommends looking at the keyword cosimulation.

Thanks. The connection with operator splitting was not apparent to me, but after some thought, I think I see the connection. I think I'll also look at papers related to "subcycling".

You left out one very important detail: are you solving exactly the same equations with both solvers, and only the time step is different?  In that case multirate methods are what you need.  If not, then you need something like operator splitting or more sophisticated additive methods.

Sorry, I should have been more clear. Not exactly the same equations.

Completely agree with these recommendations and will add "cosimulation" as another keyword to search.  I'll also note the correct link to my thesis is http://hdl.handle.net/10919/104872.

Thanks @StevenRoberts I should have just waited for you to answer this question but I've updated my answer based on your comment.
